# MongoDb Rollback Ensuring Data Consistency

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../models/User')
const RFP = require('../models/RFP')
const {body,validationResult} = require('express-validator')

router.post('/createuser',[
    body('name','Enter the Name').isLength({min:3}),
    body('email','Please enter the valid Email!!').isEmail(),
    body('phone_number').isNumeric()

    .isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('Please enter a valid phone number'),
    body('call_sign').isLength({min:3}),
    body('description').isLength({min:3}),
    body('spoc').isLength({min:3}),
    body('date', 'Date is required').notEmpty(),
],async (req,res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({error : errors.array()})
    }

    try {
        

        let rfp_user = await RFP.create({
            rfp : await generateIdentifier(),
            call_sign : req.body.call_sign,
            description : req.body.description,
            customer_name : req.body.name,
            spoc : req.body.spoc,
            date : req.body.date
        })

        let user = await User.create({
            name : req.body.name,
            email : req.body.email,
            phone_number : req.body.phone_number
        
            
        })
        


        

        res.status(200).json({ user, rfp_user });

    }catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        User.deleteOne(user)
        RFP.deleteOne(rfp_user)

        res.status(500).send({errors : error});
    }
    });

module.exports = router
```

Some of the fields in the User database are also present in the RFP database, I want to ensure that if the data recording in the RFP database fails, the data should be removed from the User database as well and vice verse.

For example, let's say the User database has fields like name, email, and phone_number, and the RFP database also has these fields. When creating a new record, I want to insert the data into both databases. However, if the data recording in the RFP database encounters an error, I want to roll back the changes and remove the data from the User database to maintain consistency.

Comment: Probably need to use transactions here